# Efficient progressive sum

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have the following table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    10 |
|  2 |    11 |
|  3 |    12 |
+----+-------+
```

I want to calculate a column on the fly to sum `value` of all the previous rows, to come up with something like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | value | offset |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 |    10 |      0 |
|  2 |    11 |     10 |
|  3 |    12 |     21 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Credit goes to [Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15383910/1083652)**.

```
select 
  id,
  value,
  nvl(
    sum(value) over (
      order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ), 0) as offset
from table
```

The great thing about analytic function `sum` is it's progressive, in the sense that in each iteration the engine remembers the value that was calculated for the previous row and only adds `value` of the previous row to the total. In other words, for each `offset` to be calculated, it is summing the previous row `offset` with `value`. This is very efficient and scales up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` values will be in sequence like `1,2,3 etc..` then

```
select a.*,(select sum(decode(a.id,1,0,b.value)) off_set from table b where b.id<=a.id-1)
from table a;
```

If your `id's` are not in sequence then try below code

```
select a.*,(select sum(decode(a.rn,1,0,b.value)) off_set from (select table.*,rownum rn from table) b 
           where b.rn<=a.rn-1)
from (select table.*,rownum rn from table) a;
```

Comment: This is an approach, but it does not scale up nicely, try to run it on a 100,000 rows.

Comment: may be it makes the difference for n number of rows 
but i was just giving another way of getting the solution !!